# Symbolic link to python 3.6 is ignored

Tags: python, symlink, which

How can the following be?

```
dims@pterosaur:~$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Aug 15 12:18 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.6
dims@pterosaur:~$ which python3.6
/usr/bin/python3.6
dims@pterosaur:~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
dims@pterosaur:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
dims@pterosaur:~$ python3.6 --version
Python 3.6.6
dims@pterosaur:~$ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.6.6
```

All commands were entered sequentially

Comment: See if running `hash -r` help.  If you previously use `python3`, the shell may have hashed the location of it.

Comment: I believe @Kusalananda is right, another option is when encountering file or permissions strangeness after modifying them, is logging out and logging in.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

Comment: Possibly a duplicate (if `bash`'s hashing was the issue): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5609/how-do-i-clear-bashs-cache-of-paths-to-executables