# Installed program executable runs from wrong location

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, gnome-shell, parcellite

I installed `parcellite` in Ubuntu (downloaded from http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/)

After installing from sources, `sudo make install`, I can see that it is installed at below location.

However, when I try to run it, it tries to run it from another path. Why is that?

```
user$ which parcellite
/usr/local/bin/parcellite

user$ parcellite -h
bash: /usr/bin/parcellite: No such file or directory
```

`$PATH` is as below

`/home/user/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`

I tried changing ownership of executable as follows. Still the problem persists.

```
user$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/parcellite 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 452K Oct  7 21:00 /usr/local/bin/parcellite
user$sudo chown user:user /usr/local/bin/parcellite
user$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/parcellite 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 452K Oct  7 21:01 /usr/local/bin/parcellite
```

I had an older version of parcellite installed. But I removed it prior to installing new version.

---

Update: @Fox's solution works. But any idea why `which` command gives correct path, despite `hash`NOT being updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had a version installed, then installed another version elsewhere, then your shell will have cached (hashed) the original path. You can clear this cache with `hash -r`. Then the next time you run the command it will be rehashed with the new path.

Note that this cache is not global, if you have several running shells you will have to update each of them.

As to why `which` sees the correct path, ["Why not use `which`"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/) is a good source of information, but the short answer is that `which` is an external command that doesn't see the shell's path cache.

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I had earlier tried `sudo updatedb` but that didn't work. I think that hash commands needs to run automatically each time a program is installed.

Comment: More info about hash was found here. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command

`hash` is a bash built-in command. The hash table is a feature of `bash`  that prevents it from having to search `$PATH` every time you type a command by caching the results in memory. The table gets cleared on events that obviously invalidate the results (such as modifying `$PATH`)

Comment: Any idea why `which` command gives correct path, despite `hash`NOT being updated?