# Repurpose a Linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Currently, I have the `zathura` program installed in my system.
What I did is writing a bash scripts redefine and program to have the right output. I also updated the `$PATH` for the scripts. However. when I run zathura command on the terminal it behave the same as the original zathura program, which is openning up a pdf file and stopping me from interacting with the terminal. I want `zathura` command to open a pdf file without taking me away from the terminal.

This is the content of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
command zathura "$1" &> /dev/null &
```

the input will be pdf file. For example, `zathura quickstart.pdf` should open a pdf file and keep me interact with the terminal sitll.

Additionally, These are the output of `which` command `echo $PATH` command :

```
which zathura
/home/anpham/scripts/zathura

echo $PATH
/home/anpham/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: @roaima thanks for the `echo` debug trig. I typed in the `hash -r` command. I also get in in the hash table. But now the script doesn't open the pdf file.

Comment: I know what's wrong. I should add the absolute path for the original zathura command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is missing its `#!` line. I would also suggest you put a debugging line immediately underneath it so you can prove to yourself you're actually running your script.

The resultant script would therefore be something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is my script - with '$1'"
/usr/bin/zathura "$1" &> /dev/null &
```

Your `$PATH` is correct, so if you find you aren't running your script, make sure you've told `bash` you've overlaid the original `zathura` by typing [`hash -r`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86012/100397)
.

Comment: With the `PATH` that he has, wouldn't this just call the script again if the script is also called `zathura`? I believe it would be better with a shell function (it's such a small thing).

Comment: @Kusalananda almost certainly, but I was trying also to illustrate how one might go about tracking down the perceived problem. The OP also provided an edit (thank you) to fix the system standard path for the tool.