# Where is the information of the hash table stored? In other words, where is its database?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-builtin

The "command hashing system" should store the path of the shell commands somewhere, right ?  Is it a database or what?  I am wondering where that is. Also, Is it encrypted ?

Do we have a way of knowing where and how the hashing system stores those commands?

I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: The information is cached in memory. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86012/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-hash-command.

Comment: That's just a feature of your shell, not of the system. The hashed commands aren't "stored" on any non-volatile medium, nor are they encrypted (why should they be). On a more practical note, you can access the command hash table in bash via either the `hash` builtin or the `BASH_CMDS` associative array.

Comment: Thanks @mosvy. The reason I asked about whether it's encrypted or not is that if you could somehow change the path of a highly used command, you could make a security hole and run a '"dangerous"  script instead. (Not that I want to hack or something; I was just curious)

Comment: That would be a very roundabout way to do it. But if you want & as I told you: `BASH_CMDS[ls]=/bin/yes`. Then use `ls`. `hash -r` to let bash forget about it.

Comment: @mosvy Wow thanks.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mosvy  But looks like it doesn't work that way. When you change the path, `ls` disappears from the hash table. Did it work for you?

Comment: @mosvy It works. Never mind. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, if you change the `PATH`, the hash table will be cleared. That's standard behaviour.

Comment: @mosvy  No, actually it works. I had a small problem with `ls` because it was aliased and its arguments were used for the substitute command. I tried some other command, and it worked. (I am using Arch. Not all distros show the same behaviour tho)